# Is this phrase in apposition?

Tags: grammatical-case

Attempting to translate this sentence from Asimov's, I, Robot:

> Donovan had time for one startled gasp as he felt himself lifted from the floor and carried up the stairs at a pace rather better than a canter.

I wrote this:

> Donovan hatte die Zeit für ein einzelnes hochgeschrecktes Schnappen nach Luft, während er fühlte, vom Boden gehoben und die Treppe nach oben getragen zu werden, **mit einem Tempo vielmehr besser als einem leichten Galopp.**

and was corrected with this:

> Donovan hatte die Zeit für ein einzelnes hochgeschrecktes Schnappen nach Luft, während er fühlte, vom Boden gehoben und die Treppe nach oben getragen zu werden, mit einem Tempo vielmehr besser **als ein leichter Galopp.**

Is not "ein leichter Galopp" in apposition to "einem Tempo". And, if so, should it not be in dative then?

Comment: This sentence is weird. I don't understand it. What are you trying to say? Please write the same sentence in English.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: The English is given as part of the question. Taken out of context it does seem a bit unclear though, and unusually phrased. Donovan is picked up and carried way by a group of people (presumably) and the speed he's being carried is a bit slower than a full run.

Comment: Almost correct. Actually, the English is saying that he is being carried a bit faster, not slower, and not a run, but a trot, particularly a horse's trot.

Comment: Die Übersetzung ist viel zu wörtlich im Satzbau und Grammatik an das Englische angelehnt und deshalb imho zwar korrekt aber kein schönes Deutsch. Donovan hatte Zeit für ein überraschtes Schnappen nach Luft als er bemerkte wie er von Boden gehoben und (wie) im rasenden Galopp die Treppe nach oben getragen wurde.

Comment: Well, I only wish I could provide everyone with beautiful German myself, but since I cannot, I am forced to submit questions with the best dregs I can muster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try this again.

"ein Leichter Galopp" is an apposition to "einem Tempo"

you could use genetive

> im Tempo eines leichten Galopps

But you should just split the sentence in two. This sounds horrible and is just bad style.

If you need one sentence, do something like this (Im not sure about the sense here but it is gramatically correct):

> Donovan hatte die Zeit für ein einzelnes hochgeschrecktes Schnappen nach Luft, während er fühlte, **langsam/schnell/in leichtem Galopp...** vom Boden gehoben und die Treppe nach oben getragen zu werden.

Also, one speed can't be better than another in german. You can do

> mit einem Tempo schneller/langsamer als einem leichten Galopp

but this sounds weird as well when added to your sentence.

Comment: Thanks. But note that, I have been officially designated a specialist in weird sounding German. Also, see: https://bit.ly/41kIWZh where there is, " Es geht uns heute nicht schlechter, sondern vielmehr besser als vor zwölf Monaten, am Beginn des letzten Jahres." Why can one time be better than another, but not one speed better than another?

Comment: Additionally, here is a better speed in German: "vor allen Dingen in die Realisierung ihrer Beschlüsse durch die Länder ein etwas besseres Tempo kommen möchte, ", which is found in DWDS: https://bit.ly/3KyiWDY

Comment: I should have better clarrified this - you can compare speeds with "besser/schlechter", but the meaning is different. In english, you can compare the actual speed with better. But in german, if you say "tempo1 ist besser als tempo2", you mean that speed 1 is preferrable to speed 2

Comment: Example from https://bit.ly/3Kxle6u : "Die Statistik zeigt, dass die Frührentner im Schnitt besser als der Durchschnitt verdient haben." Surely, this German says that the retirees earned above the average, not preferrably to the average. Similarly, why cannot, "Temp01 ist besser als Temp02," mean Temp01 is above Tempo2?

Comment: Another example: "Berliner Zeitung, 07.07.2001
So war der Durchschnitt eines Schweizer Jahrgangs besser als der Durchschnitt des besten Drittels der deutschen Schüler."

Comment: @user44591 income and skill are things which have a natural scale of more is better. No single person can honestly argue to be worse when they have or get more of it. There is no moral (?) scale attached to speed or most other units of measure. 'better' in the sense of 'more than' simply cannot be translated as 'besser' in comparisons when there is no moral judgement implied.

Comment: @planetmaker exactly. I would just add that you can use "besser" is a comparison of appropriate speeds too (opinions). If you want to say, that the a lower speed would be better suited for the current road/weather conditions, you can also use "besser" 
e.g. a driving teacher could tell you to driver slower in a tight curve - "In so einer engen Kurve wäre es besser, langsamer zu fahren!"

Comment: Thank you, but in this particular case the English is written as it is in order to include exactly that suggestion of moral judgement or valuation that the word "better" carries in English. Therefore, I believe this discussion validates its use in the German. When translating a story, like this, the translator has to make such judgements. And, by the way, that was not my question.